# KeyError on pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am applying a lambda function to a row of selected columns in a dataframe -

```
  metrics['change_in_traffic'] = metrics[[
      'current_position', 'traffic'
  ]].apply(
      lambda x: _change(x, weights_for_position),
      axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am doing this in the _change function -

```
  current_position, traffic = x
  new_position = current_position - _POSITION_CHANGE
  if (current_position > _POSITION_CHANGE) and (new_position in weights_for_position) and (
      current_position in weights_for_position):
    return (weights_for_position[new_position] - weights_for_position[current_position]) * query_traffic
  return 0
```

weights_for_position is a dict.

I am getting a KeyError on the return - `KeyError: (679, 'occurred at index 36967')` although I am checking the the current_position and new_position are in the dict. I checked for issues with apply, but most solutions say add axis=1, which I am already doing.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Can you share an example of the `weights_for_position` dict? Also, `new_position` appears to be a number (int?), is it possible that your keys are strings?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)